# Phonegap not running javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ios7

I am trying to use phonegap but for some reason is my javascript not running. What i have tried so far is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListner("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert('hey');
            document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
            document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
        }

        function onOnline() {
            alert('device is online');
        }

        function onOffline() {
            alert('device is offline');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

but for some reason am i not getting a alert. I am using phonegap 2.9.0 on IOS 7

what i also tryed is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Empty
}

// alert dialog dismissed
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

// Show a custom alert
//
function showAlert() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'You are the winner!',  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
    );
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: iOS7's Javascript ignores "alert()" calls... FYI

Comment: Some browsers don't show `alert`. Try `console.log` instead

Comment: what do i need to use than instead?

Comment: consol.log does not work :/

Comment: @MeQube I hope you tried consol>e<.log and not `consol.log`

Comment: It's **console.log("my MSG")** not **consol.log**

Comment: i replaced alert with console.log("MSG") but that is also not working

Comment: The code you posted is missing an ending </html> tag if that matters.

Comment: Try just running this in a desktop browser and 1) inspecting the elements and 2) looking at the log. Everything should work the same as on mobile since you aren't relying on deviceready.

Answer (score 2):

```
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
```

These functions will work on establishing a new internet connection and disabling network connection only

It won't work when you open the app. These events listeners 'online' and 'offline' are mainly used to track if an internet connection is available.

Also you should not use alert function which might not be supported in ios 7. Use notification class in phonegap for alerts

Comment: but why don't i see then the alert on onDeviceReady()?

Comment: also check if you have added correct phonegap.js file in your project

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working at my end and might be you forgot to added cordova.js

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is ready
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Empty
        }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alert
     function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
                                     'You are the winner!',  // message
                                     alertDismissed,         // callback
                                     'Game Over',            // title
                                     'Done'                  // buttonName
                                     );
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert();">Show Alert</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this depends on which version of phonegap is used. With phonegap 3+, you shouldn't manually include cordova.js or phonegap.js, the included is automatically added when you build the project. And you should never include cordova.js and phonegap.js since phonegap.js loads cordova.js